# Attempting to Write to a text file using f.write in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to write information to a text file. I have a class "Student" that has a "title" and "grade"
I am new to python and am unsure of proper syntax for f.write.
I have already used input to get a student name, which is in "stud" which is of type "Student"

I have been attempting to amend the syntax, but to no avail

```
from studentStruct import Student
from assignments import Assignments

def SaveStudentToStudentList(stud):
    f = open("studentlist.txt", "a")
    f.write(str(stud.name) + (" ") + str(stud.grade) + ("\n"))
    f.close()

def CalculateStudentGrade(assignmentList, assignNum):
    sum = 0
    i = 0
    total = 0
    while i < assignNum:
        print("Enter the grade for " + assignmentList[i].title)
        mark = input("")
        sum += float(mark)*float(assignmentList[i].weight)
        total += float(assignmentList[i].weight)
        i += 1

    grade = round(sum/total)
    return grade

def DisplayStudentList(studentList, numOfStudents):
    return

numOfStudents = 0
studentList = []
assignmentList = []
assignNum = 0
canUseThree = False
canUseOne = True

print("|*|*|GRADEBOOK v1.0|*|*|\n(1): Enter First student and assessments\n(2): Display Student List\n (3): Enter New student\n (4): Exit\n")

while 1:
    choice = input("")

    if choice == "1":
        if not canUseOne:
            continue

        while 1:
            print("Enter an assignment name. Type STOP if done: \n")
            assign = input("")
            if assign == "STOP":
                break
            print("Enter the weight: \n")
            weight = input("")
            assignmentList.append(Assignments(assign, weight))
            assignNum += 1

        print("Enter the student name: ")
        StudentName = input("")
        grade = CalculateStudentGrade(assignmentList, assignNum)
        print(("Student has achieved ") +str(grade))
        if grade < 50:
            print("This student has failed the course.")
        if grade > 100:
            print("Student has over-achieved. A mark of 100 will be submitted.")
            grade = 100;
        studentList.append(Student(StudentName, grade))
        canUseOne = False
        SaveStudentToStudentList(studentList[numOfStudents])
        numOfStudents += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`f.write` can take a string as an argument. So just pass a proper string.

```
f.write(str(stud.name)  + " " + str(stud.grade) + "\n")
```

Comment: You'll need to post your whole code for us to help with that

Comment: def SaveToList(stud):
    f = open("studentlist.txt", "a")
    f.write(str(stud.name) + (" ") + str(stud.grade) + ("\n"))
    f.close()
...
while 1:
    choice = input("")
    if choice == "1":
        if not canUseOne:
            continue
        while 1:
            print("Enter an assignment name. Type STOP if done: \n")
            assign = input("")
            if assign == "STOP":
                break
            assignNum += 1
        studentList.append(Student(StudentName, grade))
        SaveToList(studentList[numOfStudents])
        numOfStudents += 1

Comment: I omitted anything that didn't appear relevant, that's a bear bones of the code. Not sure why it runs forever after the function is called

Comment: Please edit the question wit this code. Formatting doesn't work very well in comments

Comment: I'm trying to do that, but it's saying my code isn't formatted properly

Comment: I am, or at least I think I am, some of it works but other parts it is not going into the grey box. Could you show an example of how to format that?

Comment: ```
like this
```

Comment: The problem is that it is not perserving the new lines when I paste in the code

Comment: What was the issue again?

Comment: When it calls "SaveStudentToStudentList", the program never ends, it just keeps going and does not display anything

Comment: You have that call inside a `while 1` loop. After which there is an `input("")` - so your program is waiting for input.

Comment: Put a `print` right after the call to `Save` and check if that is getting printed

Comment: while i <= numOfStudents

Comment: Do you know why it is telling me this is improper syntax?

Comment: Error message, please?

Comment: My bad, I forgot the colon. I'm so used to C from the course I took

Answer (score 0):

You can create the text string first and then write it

```
text = '{} {}\n'.format(str(stud.name), str(stud.grade))
f.write(text)
```

For e.g.

```
text = '{} {}\n'.format(str('John'), str('A'))
#John A
f.write(text)
```